# Python crawler not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd like to grab all business name link on (http://mokorea.com/yp_business_list_major.php?cat=4)

Here is my Python code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import requests
from scrapy.selector import Selector

def fetch_page(url):
    '''1. 웹페이지 다운로드'''
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def upso_list_from_listpage(url):
    '''2.목록 페이`enter code here`지에서 강의 링크등 추출'''
    html = fetch_page(url)
    sel = Selector(text=html)
    upso_list = sel.xpath('//*[@id="List_0"]/div[4]').extract()
    #upso_list = sel.css('.container results .talk-link .media__message a::attr(herf)').extract()
    return upso_list
from pprint import pprint
pprint(upso_list_from_listpage('http://mokorea.com/yp_business_list_major.php?cat=4'))
```

and I try to run py file on prompt, nothing showing up.

[image: 1]

Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: Can you copy the html structure of that site so we can see it?

Comment: you can test your xpath pattern against your HTML using online tools like this one: http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: It is AJAX generated page, you should use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) or something like it.

Answer (score 0):

It is AJAX generated page.

You can use this [link](http://mokorea.com/ajax/makeBusinessList.php?_method=get&grp=&major=4&cat=&keyword=&hchar=&recom=&page=1&dist=500&gLat=59.8767&gLong=30.4016) for example and xpath selector like this:

```
sel.xpath('//*[@id="List_0"]/div[4]/span/a/text()').extract()
```

here you will obtain text from first line. After that you should:

1. Iterate through div id's ("List_0", "List_1" etc) to get another lines.
2. Analyze GET-parameters in included link, correct them and loop which you want (specially `page`)

Comment: Thank you so much. its working now.   I have two more question for you.  how did you get that link  and what does  AJAX generated page mean? Is Ajax page hard to get data? or.. something else?   I'm kind of newbi.

Comment: [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) in this case means bunch of javascripts on this web page. To get this link you should use Developer tools in any browser and a bit of care. Open Network tab and analyze requests made by web page contents.